# ionic v3 when make and update in the app to the data it is updating in the database but not in the app

Tags: php, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic and I am trying to understand an app that has basic http query to communicate with the database, but I am facing a problem. 
There is a page that show a list which has been taken from the database. There are two operations that can be performed on this list - insert and update. The problem occurres when I try to make an update. The record in the database is updated but not the list in the application is not. However, when I insert a new record the list got updated with the new record including all previous changes, that were not shown in the list.

Here is the type script for the list page:

```
export class CrudHttpListPage {
  items: any;

  constructor(public loading: LoadingProvider, private toast: ToastProvider, public modal: ModalController, private crud: CrudHttpProvider) { }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.load();
  }

  load() {
    this.loading.present();
    this.crud.read.then(res => {
      this.items = res;
      if (res) this.loading.dismiss();
    });
  }

  add() {
    let modal = this.modal.create('CrudHttpDetailPage', { action: 1 });
    modal.present();
    modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data) this.load();
    });
  }

  edit(item) {
    let modal = this.modal.create('CrudHttpDetailPage', { data: item, action: 2 });
    modal.present();
    modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
      if (data) this.load();
    });
  }
```

Here is the typescript code for the add and edit page:

```
export class CrudHttpDetailPage {
  private form: FormGroup;
  action: number;
  data: any = { title: '', text: '' };

  constructor(private view: ViewController, private toast: ToastProvider, private loading: LoadingProvider, private crud: CrudHttpProvider, private fb: FormBuilder, public params: NavParams) {
    this.action = params.data.action;
    this.data = params.data && params.data.data || this.data;
    console.log(params.data);

    this.form = this.fb.group({
      id: [this.data && this.data.id],
      title: [this.data && this.data.title, Validators.required],
      text: [this.data && this.data.text, Validators.required]
    });
  }

  submit() {
    this.loading.present();
    console.log(this.form.value);
    this.crud.save(this.form.value).then(data => {
      // this.dataNotes.id = data;
      console.log(data);
      this.loading.dismiss();
      this.view.dismiss(this.form.value);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
      this.loading.dismiss();
      this.toast.showWithClose(err);
      this.close();
    });
  }

  close() {
    this.view.dismiss();
  }

}
```

Here are the http operations:

```
const SERVER_URL: any = {
    getNormal: ConstantVariable.APIURL + 'index.php/tbl_note',
    getLimit: ConstantVariable.APIURL + 'limit.php',
};

@Injectable()
export class CrudHttpProvider {

    limitData: number = 10;
    datas: any = [];

    constructor(public http: Http) {
        this.datas = null;
    }

    get read() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.http.get(SERVER_URL.getNormal).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data.dataNotes);
                resolve(data.dataNotes);
            });
        });
    }



    save(item) {
        let headers: any = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }),
            options: any = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        if (item.id) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.http.post(SERVER_URL.getNormal + '/' + item.id, item, options).map(res => res.json()).subscribe((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    resolve(data.dataNotes);
                }, (err) => {
                    reject(err);
                    console.log("error: " + err);
                });
            });
        }
        else {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                this.http.post(SERVER_URL.getNormal, item, options)
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .subscribe(data => {
                        // console.log(data);
                        resolve(data.dataNotes[0].id);
                    }, error => {
                        console.log("error " + error);
                    });
            });
        }
    }
```

and last here is the PHP file:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    require_once('config.php');

    // get the HTTP method, path and body of the request
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    $request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'));
    $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

    // retrieve the table and key from the path
    $table = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/i','',array_shift($request));
    $key = array_shift($request)+0;

    // escape the columns and values from the input object
    $columns = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/i','',array_keys($input));
    $values = array_map(function ($value) use ($link) {
      if ($value===null) return null;
      return mysqli_real_escape_string($link,(string)$value);
    },array_values($input));

    // build the SET part of the SQL command
    $set = '';
    for ($i=0;$i<count($columns);$i++) {
      $set.=($i>0?',':'').'`'.$columns[$i].'`=';
      $set.=($values[$i]===null?'NULL':'"'.$values[$i].'"');
    }

    // create SQL based on HTTP method
    if ($method == "POST" AND $key != "") { $method = 'PUT'; }
    if ($method == "GET" AND $key != "") { $method = 'DELETE'; }
    switch ($method) {
      case 'GET':
        $sql = "select * from `$table`".($key?" WHERE id=$key":''); break;
      case 'PUT':
        $sql = "update `$table` set $set where id=$key"; break;
      case 'POST':
        $sql = "insert into `$table` set $set"; break;
      case 'DELETE':
        $sql = "delete from `$table` where id=$key"; break;
    }

    // excecute SQL statement
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

    // die if SQL statement failed
    if (!$result) {
      http_response_code(404);
      die(mysqli_error());
    }

    // print results, insert id or affected row count
    echo "{\"status\":\"ok\", \"dataNotes\":";

    if ($method == 'GET') {
        if (!$key) echo '[';
        for ($i=0;$i<mysqli_num_rows($result);$i++) {
            echo ($i>0?',':'').json_encode(mysqli_fetch_object($result));
          }

        if (!$key) echo ']';
    } elseif ($method == 'POST') {
        $set = '"id":"'.mysqli_insert_id($link).'"';
        for ($i=1;$i<count($columns);$i++) {
          $set.=($i>0?',':'').'"'.$columns[$i].'":';
          $set.=($values[$i]===null?'NULL':'"'.$values[$i].'"');
        }
        echo "[{".$set."}]";
    } elseif ($method == 'DELETE') {
        echo '[{"id":"'.$key.'"}]';
    } else {
      echo mysqli_affected_rows($link);
    }
    echo "}";

    // close mysql connection
    mysqli_close($link);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally solved the problem. what cause the issue is that i have two files to make a connection to the database one for the website and the other is for the mobile application and it seems the one which i use in the mobile application is broken so i remove this file and connect to the old file and the problem solved

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be here:

```
  edit(item) {
    let modal = this.modal.create('CrudHttpDetailPage', { data: item, action: 2 });
    modal.present();
    modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
      if (data) this.load(); // <---- seems this.load() is not executing
    });
  }
```

Seems `this.load()` is not executing after `modal.onDidDismiss`:
- check modal is dismissing
- check if `data` is not null/undefined
- check running `this.load()`, with no if() statement, does it run?
you may be able to find the answer there

```
  edit(item) {
    let modal = this.modal.create('CrudHttpDetailPage', { data: item, action: 2 });
    modal.present();
    modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
      console.log('Modal has dismissed!!');
      // if (data) this.load(); // comment for check
      this.load();
    });
  }
```

Comment: it did not work the model is dismissing and  i checked that `data` is not null and one last thing when i want to access the page it wont show the new data either i must add a new record to see the updated data

Comment: what my best guess is that there is a problem in the php file exactly in the `json_encode` function it is the one which responsible for sending data from php file to ts file

Comment: ok, I would recommend to first verify backend is working correctly and then continue with frontend, you´ll be able to isolate problems more easily. Use postman to test backend directly.

Comment: okay i have checked the JSON output in the browser and in postman and they gave a different result in the postman it shows the exact data that is in the database and i tried to copy and past the URL in the browser to see the result and it shows the old data and i figured out that in order to show the new data i have to reload the page and to conclude this  each time i want to make an update in the application it wont show the new data until i reload the PHP file in the browser or make an insert

Comment: i am not sure but after searching for a while i found out that the problem could just be a stale data in MYSQL so any ideas